# Excel 2007 formula to display 3 cells of data if 2 cells are filled

Tags: excel

I have a worksheet with column A (rows 1-200) filled with text, column B will have a date entered and column C will have a name entered.  Column A is prefilled, but columns B and C will be updated periodically.  I need a formula to copy all 3 cells of data into worksheet 2, but only when columns B & C are filled.

I also want to be able to just show the information that is complete without any blank rows on Worksheet 2 without formatting or filtering out the blanks.

Thank you in advance to anyone who answers

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: I am new to formula, but have tried =if(and(isblank(B1),(isblank(c1),(isblank(d1),b1,c1,d1,""))

Comment: Show us what you've tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say we start with data like this in *Sheet1*:

[image]

We will use column **D** as a "helper" column.  In **D1** enter:

<strike>=IF(COUNTA(B1:C1)=2,1,"")</strike>

```
=IF(COUNTBLANK(B1:C1)>0,"",1)
```

and in **D2** enter:

<strike>=IF(COUNTA(B2:C2)=2,1+MAX($D$1:D1),"")</strike>

```
=IF(COUNTBLANK(B2:C2)>0,"",1+MAX($D$1:D1))
```

and copy down.  Column **D** marks the specific rows to appear in the other sheet:

[image]

Then in *Sheet2* cell **A1** we enter:

```
=IFERROR(MATCH(ROW(),Sheet1!D:D,0),"")
```

and copy down

In cell **B1** we enter:

```
=IF(A1="","",INDEX(Sheet1!A:A,$A1))
```

We first copy **B1** to **C1** through **D1**.  We then copy **B1** thru **D1** downwards.  This gives us in *Sheet2*:

[image]

As data is modified in *Sheet1* the result in *Sheet2* will update automatically.

**EDIT#1:**

Updated the *Sheet1* column **D** formulas.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time, but - this would work except that I have formula in columns B and C to copy the data across from another worksheet, so the count is picking up the formula and counting every cell

Comment: @user427777  a small change will be needed we can use *CountBlank()* rather than *CountA* ...........check back later!!

Comment: I'm doing something wrong If I replace CountA with countblank() or with countblank(A) I don't get any count. Where do I reference column A?

Comment: I've just seen your edit above, so ignore the last question.  Thank you so much for all your help

Comment: Look at my **EDIT** the old formulas are crossed out............just use the new formulas